# Can you add a button inside a custom TableCell in material UI?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, frontend

Currently, I am creating a table with material-ui, and the last column of the TableHead should contain an upload button. Something like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeDAZ.jpg)

I have tried the following:

```
const StyledTableCell = withStyles((theme) => ({
  head: {
    color: theme.palette.text.dark,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.light,
  },
  body: {
    fontSize: 14,
  }
}))(TableCell);

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <StyledTableRow>
            <StyledTableCell align="left">Position</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Defect Type by Worker</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Tool Decision by Worker</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                Upload
              </Button>
            </StyledTableCell>
          </StyledTableRow>
        </TableHead>

        <TableBody>
          ...
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
```

But react will not render if you directly add a button component inside a custom tablecell. Is there a way to add a button inside a custom tablecell? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I try your code and because you didn't provide the StyledTableRow code so I change it to TableRow and the button is working fine.

[image]

So maybe your problem is in the StyledTableRow, you can try my code like below:

```js
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <StyledTableCell align="left">Position</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Defect Type by Worker</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Tool Decision by Worker</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                Upload
              </Button>
            </StyledTableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
```